# How do I know that this app is not secretly sending my data elsewhere?

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

How do I know that what I store in this app is only saved locally, and the dev doesn't have access to my files?

https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/foto-segrete-kyms-foto-video/id462182115?mt=8